# How can i update data to a related field before saving Django model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to update the user instance of an assigned file when the file is transferred. The transfer POST action goes through successfully without any errors but then the user instance of the file model is not updated with "transfer_to" user instance. This is what I have done so far:

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    file_type_choice = (
        ('General', 'General'),
        ('Personal', 'Personal')
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='files')
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=file_type_choice)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.file_name}'

    def get_absolute_url_file_transfer(self):
        return reverse('file_transfer', args=[self.pk])


class Transfer(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey('File', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    transfer_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transfers_from', null=True)
    transfer_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='transfers_to', null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.transfer_from} {self.transfer_to}'
```

**forms.py**

```
class FileTransferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transfer
        fields = ['transfer_from', 'transfer_to', ]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def outgoing_file_list(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        files = File.objects.all()
    else:
        files = File.objects.filter(Q(transfer__transfer_to=request.user) | Q(user=request.user))

    context = {
        'files': files,
    }

    return render(request, 'outgoing_file_list.html', context)


def file_transfer(request, pk):
    file = get_object_or_404(File, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FileTransferForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_edit = form.save(commit=False)
            form_edit.file = file
            file.user = form_edit.transfer_to
            file.save()
            form_edit.save()
            return redirect('outgoing_file_list')
    else:
        form = FileTransferForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'file': file,
    }

    return render(request, 'file_transfer.html', context)
```

[form_edit.tranfer_to does not return user instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY30H.png)

Comment: Hi Francis. Are you trying to overwrite form_edit? Why didn't you save the file model after update the user object on file?

Comment: yes i am trying to overwrite form_edit and after saving the user object on file model, it doesn't give me the desire result. form_edit.transfer_to returns nothing and i want help to be able to get the transfer_to user instance from the form_edit and save it to the user on the file model.

Comment: @FrancisAkabo is your submitted form even valid? If it was valid you should get an error on `obj.save()` something like `NameError: name 'obj' is not defined`. Try `print(form.errors)` in the else part.

Comment: I subsequently modified form_edit to obj for clarity but I've reverted it. There are no errors after post. Pls look at the attached screen shot I took from pycharm and help me figure how to retrieve the user instance of transfer_to

Comment: When the transfer_to field is on the File model, I am to reference and update it and overwrite the user field with it but when I implemented the transfer_to on the Transfer model and relating to the File model, I'm unable to reference it

Comment: Just like @Murat Demir suggested, file model was not saved after the update. Much to be desired looking back to the mistakes i made starting off with Django : )